# Converting list of array to a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, type-conversion

I have a list of arrays something like this:

```
  list:
       [[['23456', '23456']], [['459687', '201667'],['769687', '203416']]
```

How can I remove the the nested [] to have a list of list something like this:

```
   list:
       [['23456', '23456'], ['459687', '201667'],['769687', '203416']]
```

Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? are there always only one element? is the first one supposed to be missing a closing bracket?

Comment: They are always two elements in one sublist. I am trying different ways to convert them to make the list clear (from the nested brackets) that I can use it in a loop for a simple comparison. E.g., I want to check if a list with two elements (e.g., my list: ['23456', '23456']) is a member of a bigger list with multiple sublists like ({['23456', '23456'], ['459687', '201667'],['769687', '203416']]) .

Comment: You might try: `sum(list, [])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_list = []
for sub_list in nested_list:
    if type(sub_list[0]) == list:
        for potential_list in sub_list:
            if type(potential_list) == list:
                new_list.append(potential_list)
    elif type(sub_list[0]) == str:
        new_list.append(sub_list)
    else:
        print(type(sub_list)) # if you get here, you have even more weird nesting than in your example
```

This will handle your example but won't handle nesting deeper than the example. If you need deeper nesting create a function similar to the following but use recursion

Comment: This works. many thanks